# less guards : positive percentage

Tags: css, less

I've tried goggling it, with no results, sadly.

What I'd like to do is a lighten / darken mixin, depending on the percentage : if percentage is < 0, then do "darken(@color, @light)", else if percentage is > 0, then do "lighten(@color, @light)".

Something like this :

```
._changeColor(@color, @light) when (ispercentage(@light)) and (@light > 0%) {
    color: lighten(@color, @light);
}
```

but it doesn't want to work. I've used things like

```
.mixin (@a) when (isnumber(@a)) and (@a > 0) {...}
```

and it works just fine... 
Any ideas if there's something special to do for percentages ?

Thanks ! 
=)

Answer (score 1):

What exactly is the problem besides "doesn't work"?

This

```
._changeColor(@color, @light) when (ispercentage(@light)) and (@light > 0%) {
    color: lighten(@color, @light);
}


._changeColor(@color, @light) when (ispercentage(@light)) and  (@light < 0%) {
    color: darken(@color, @light * -1);
}

.foo {
  ._changeColor(#ff00ff, -10%);
}
```

works [in the online LESS converter](http://www.dopefly.com/LESS-Converter/less-converter.html).